# AWS CodeBuild + CodePipeline: "No matching artifact paths found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am attempting to get CodePipeline to fetch my code from GitHub and build it with CodeBuild. The first (Source) step works fine. But the second (Build) step fails during the "UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS" part. Here are the relevant log statements:

```
[Container] 2017/01/12 17:21:31 Assembling file list
[Container] 2017/01/12 17:21:31 Expanding MyApp
[Container] 2017/01/12 17:21:31 Skipping invalid artifact path MyApp
[Container] 2017/01/12 17:21:31 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS Success: false
[Container] 2017/01/12 17:21:31 Phase context status code: ARTIFACT_ERROR Message: No matching artifact paths found
[Container] 2017/01/12 17:21:31 Runtime error (No matching artifact paths found)
```

My app has a buildspec.yml in its root folder. It looks like:

```
version: 0.1

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - echo `$BUILD_COMMAND`

artifacts:
  discard-paths: yes
  files:
    - MyApp
```

It would appear that the "MyApp" in my buildspec.yml should be something different, but I'm pouring through all of the AWS docs to no avail (what else is new?). How can I get it to upload the artifact correctly?

Comment: Have you figured out this I am facing exactly same problem with my nodejs app. If you can please help.

Comment: @Jeet Yeah, I think I needed to use '**/*' as the source, or something like that. Look for the "artifacts" section: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-syntax

Comment: Thank you John for the quick response. I would give it a try. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The artifacts should refer to files downloaded from your Source action or generated as part of the Build action in CodePipeline. For example, this is from a buildspec.yml I wrote:

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - appspec.yml
    - target/SampleMavenTomcatApp.war
    - scripts/*
```

When I see that you used **MyApp** in your artifacts section, it makes me think you're referring to the **OutputArtifacts** of the Source action of CodePipeline. Instead, you need to refer to the  files it downloads and stores there (i.e. S3) and/or it generates and stores there.

You can find a sample of a CloudFormation template that uses CodePipeline,  CodeBuild, CodeDeploy, and CodeCommit here: https://github.com/stelligent/aws-codedeploy-sample-tomcat/blob/master/codebuild-cpl-cd-cc.json The `buildspec.yml` is in the same forked repo.

Comment: "you need to refer to the files it downloads and stores there (i.e. S3) and/or it generates and stores there" That makes sense, but how do I know what the names of those values are? I looked in the Source action's S3 bucket, and they appear to be randomly generated names.

Comment: Sorry, I think my S3 reference confused things. To clarify, in the artifacts/files section of your buildspec, you'll list the files you're using to build from your Source repository (i.e. the files in GitHub - and not the randomly generated names generated from CodePipeline) and any relevant files generated from your build process. It's unclear based on the supplied information which language/platform you're building on.

Comment: Ah, I now understand. Man, the documentation with these tools is incredibly confounding. Thanks!

Comment: The phrasing "No matching artifact paths found" is very confusing.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I received this error because I had changed directory in my build stage (the java project I am building is in a subdirectory) and did not change back to the root. Adding `cd ..`at the end of the build stage did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Buildspec artifacts are information about where CodeBuild can find the build output and how CodeBuild prepares it for uploading to the Amazon S3 output bucket.

For the error "No matching artifact paths found" Couple of things to check:

1. Artifacts file(s) specified on buildspec.yml file has **correct path and file name.**

`artifacts:
     files:
       -'FileNameWithPath'`

2. If you are using .gitignore file, make sure file(s) specified on Artifacts section
   **is not included in .gitignore file**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There was the same issue as @jd96 wrote. I needed to return to the root directory of the project to export artifact.

```
build:
 commands:
  - cd tasks/jobs
  - make build
  - cd ../..
post_build:
 commands:
  - printf '[{"name":"%s","imageUri":"%s"}]' $IMAGE_REPO_NAME $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json
```

artifacts:
files: imagedefinitions.json

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue, and the solution to fix the problem was "packaging directories and files inside the archive with no further root folder creation".

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-war-hw.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're like me and ran into this problem whilst using Codebuild within a CodePipeline arrangement.

You need to use the following

```
- printf '[{"name":"container-name-here","imageUri":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/imagedefinitions.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Artifacts are the stuff you want from your build process - whether compiled in some way or just files copied straight from the source. So the build server pulls in the code, compiles it as per your instructions, then copies the specified files out to S3.

In my case using Spring Boot + Gradle, the output jar file (when I `gradle bootJar` this on my own system) is placed in build/libs/demo1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, so I set the following in buildspec.yml:

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - build/libs/*.jar
```

This one file appears for me in S3, optionally in a zip and/or subfolder depending on the options chosen in the rest of the Artifacts section

Answer (score 0):

try using the version 0.2 of the buildspec

here is a typical example for nodejs

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Nothing to do in the pre_build phase...
  build:
    commands:
      - npm install
      - npm run build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on
artifacts:
  files:
    - appspec.yml
    - build/*
```